# C# With Ram Optimize

Tags: c#, optimization, autoit, ram

you can optimize the RAM usage of an application with the following code with AutoIt. How is this in C#, How do I set up?

```
Func _ReduceMemory($iPid)
    Local $ai_Handle = DllCall("kernel32.dll", 'int', 'OpenProcess', 'int', 0x1f0fff, 'int', False, 'int', $iPid)
    Local $ai_Return = DllCall("psapi.dll", 'int', 'EmptyWorkingSet', 'long', $ai_Handle[0])
    Return $ai_Return[0]
EndFunc
```

Comment: This doesn't "optimize" anything.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not. Unless you are using Windows 95. Please read : "[Why Memory Optimizers and RAM Boosters Are Worse Than Useless](http://www.howtogeek.com/171424/why-memory-optimizers-and-ram-boosters-are-worse-than-useless/)".

You can use [this wiki](http://pinvoke.net/) in order to call unmanaged dll from C#.

Comment: Dude, this is the autoit code above with the c# application I wrote, I'm significantly optimized the RAM usage. Falls from 25 MB to 2 MB. And that c#'s If you can do it, why I'll use a different language. The DLL that I want from you C#'S use of the show.